# Child component not re-rendering from state change from one parent, but re-renders from another parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have a child component `PostItem` that takes a post object from redux state as a prop:

```
const PostItem = ({
      post: { _id, text, name, avatar, user, likes}, //from redux state
      //...
   }) => {

   //...

   const handleLike = e => {
      likePost(_id); //ACTION
   };

   return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className='post bg-white vert-m-1 p-1'>
          <div>
            <p className='vert-m-1'>{text}</p>
            <button className='btn' onClick={e => handleLike(e)}>
              <i className='fas fa-thumbs-up'></i> <span>{likes.length}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
   );
}
```

I have an action `likePost` that changes state in a `reducer`:

```
    case LIKE_A_POST:
    case UNLIKE_A_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id
            ? {
                ...post,
                likes: payload.likes 
              }
            : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
```

To my knowledge, React component re-renders upon state or props change.

I render the child component, `PostItem`, from 2 parent components: `Posts` and `Comment`.

If `PostItem` is rendered from `Posts`, triggering the action `likePost` will automatically re-render the component. This makes sense because my redux state changes which will cause a re-render. In addition, since the redux state is passed as a prop to `PostItem`, changing the redux state will change the props which also triggers a re-render.

However, when `PostItem` is rendered from `Comment`, triggering `likePost` does not cause `PostItem` to re-render even though the `likePost` action still changes my redux state. I can see in the redux Developer tools that the state is in fact changed, but a re-render is not triggered. In this case, the redux state is also being passed as a prop to `PostItem`, but a change in props is not triggering a re-render.

Why is `PostItem` re-rendering in the `Posts` parent component, but not `Comment` parent component? Both `Posts` and `Comment` pass a post object (containing my redux state) as a prop to `PostItem`.

Following advice online, my reducer uses the spread operator to avoid using the same object reference.  Both `Posts` and `Comment` use the same action to change my redux state, meaning state is changing in both cases. Both `Posts` and `Comment` pass the redux state as a prop to `PostItem`, meaning props is being changed in both cases.

> For full reproducible code, I'm not sure how to proceed since it
>   involves accessing a database, requiring my database URI as well as a
>   JSON Secret Web Token. Advise on how to provide a Minimal,
>   Reproducible Example please.
>
> A link to my repo: https://github.com/boxcarcoder/ExplorersConnect
>
> Please look in the `reprex` branch for a minimal version of the
>   following files:
>
> The components PostItem, Posts, and Comment:  explorersConnect/client/src/components/posts
>
> The actions: explorersConnect/client/src/actions
>
> The reducers: explorersConnect/client/src/reducers

Comment: prepare [example]

Comment: How do I include redux action and reducer to Stack Snippets? As well as multiple JS files (each for a React component)? I only see a window for HTML, CSS, and JS which seems to look like one file per filetype. I have streamlined the PostItem, Posts, and Comment components, as well as the post action and reducers, but am not sure if I need to, or how to, include all the backend code in a Stack Snippet. Will a link to my repo suffice?

Comment: use codesandbox or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

The key is to realize that although `likePost` changes the `likes` of a post, this post is not the `post` redux state, but a post within the `posts` array redux state. That means triggering `likePost` is triggering a change to `posts`, which is a prop to `Posts`, but not `Comment`. The wrong assumption was that changing `Posts` will be a state change that triggers `Comment` to re-render, but `Comment`'s props does not change so there is no re-render.

Since `Comment`'s props are `post`, the `likePost` action and reducer should change `post` in the redux state, so that a change in props and state will trigger a re-render of `Comment`.

There was confusion between changing state:
Changing `state.posts` is not the same as changing `state.post`, even though `state.posts` is, in theory, just an array of all `state.post`s. The key is understanding that a change in a component's Props is necessary, not just a state change. The state change has to directly affect a component's props.

Comment: State change forces rerendering generally [works on virtual DOM] - updating real DOM depends on rendering result props changes (optimizations, read about "reconcilation" process). ... Using `useSelector()` hooks should give you more clear view of dependencies.